# Consuming a Mono<T> in a Spring web Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, asynchronous, reactor

I'm currently trying to understand Reactor and refactored a service method that returned an `Optional<CompanyDetails>` to use Reactor's `Mono<CompanyDetails>` instead:

```
public Mono<CompanyDetails> findOne(String id) {
    CompanyDetails result = retrieveFromSomewhere(id);
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(result);
}
```

From my understanding this should emit either `empty()` or `just(result)`.
I consume the service in a Spring web Controller like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public DeferredResult<CompanyDetails> getCompany(@PathVariable String id) {
    final DeferredResult<CompanyDetails> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    companyService.findOne(id)
            .consume(result::setResult);
    return result;
}
```

This works fine if a result was found, but if `findOne` emits `empty()` it runs into a timeout. I could call `get()` explicitly and check for `null`, but that  feels totally wrong.

Also: Before refactoring, `getCompany` threw a `NotFoundException` if no result was found, is that possible at all, or am I on the wrong track entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer myself: First it turned out that Reactor's `Mono` has a `toCompletableFuture`-method and Spring MVC can also use that instead of `DeferredResult`. Failing the `CompletableFuture` throws an Exception just as expected.

To fail, `Mono` has to emit an `error` instead of `empty`:

```
public Mono<CompanyDetails> findOne(String id) {
    CompanyDetails result = retrieveFromSomewhere(id);
    return Mono
            .justOrEmpty(result)
            .otherwiseIfEmpty(Mono.error(...));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CompletableFuture<CompanyDetails> getCompany(@PathVariable String id) {
    return companyService.findOne(id)
            .toCompletableFuture();
}
```

Much better now.